# Why is the method deleting the element inside my array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to create my own .sort  method as an exercise in a ruby book, using recursion, and for some reason they haven't taught me the spaceship operator yet. My code works to get the smallest value - apple - and puts it in the sorted array, and it even repeats using the recursion, and resets the array to repeat the process to add the second smallest word. The problem is for some reason it removes the smallest word -apple- and I can't figure out why. I know where I think - in the else myArray.length == 1 statement when I pop the element off the array, but why is it removing from the sortedArray too?

sortedArray ends up with value apple, then when it does recursion it SHOULD be sortedArray = ['apple', 'banana' …]   but it removes apple, then it removes banana etc… until I end up with sortedArray = ['quincy']

I have tried moving my arrays to multiple places, and I've tried adding to the sortedWords array in multiple places but it is always deleting or resetting the sortedWords array.

It looks like I'm really close since I've got the alphabetizing working. How do I get it to add all the items to the sortedWords array?

```
ArrayofWords = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat', 'elephant', 'apple', 'banana', 'quincy', 'boo']

# Why is it deleting, or replacing my sortedWords array? If you run this code you will     notice that the sortedWords array
# is giving me the smallest word in the array, but then I add the recursive part, and somehow the previous smallestword
#gets deleted... but I have never in any part of my code say delete or replace the sorted    array...

def sortTheArray myArray
  unsortedWords = []
  sortedWords   = []
  smallestValue = ''

  while myArray.length != 0
    if myArray.first < myArray.last
      unsortedWords.push(myArray.last)
        myArray.pop
    elsif myArray.first > myArray.last
      unsortedWords.push(myArray.first)
      myArray.delete_at(0)
    else myArray.length == 1
      sortedWords.push(myArray.first)
      myArray.pop # This is my problem area I think???
    end # if else


    #puts 'sorted words'  
    #puts sortedWords
    #puts 'unsortedWords'
    #puts unsortedWords
  end # while

  puts 'sorted words'  
  puts sortedWords
  puts 'unsortedWords'
  puts unsortedWords

  myArray = unsortedWords

  while myArray.length > 0
    sortTheArray myArray
  end #while

end # sortTheArray
sortTheArray ArrayofWords
```

most of those puts's are not necessary, I was just trying to figure out where the problem was.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong title at the beginning. I was in the middle of asking a question last night and it saved, so I forgot to change the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got numerous problems with your code. For example, you seem to want to accumulate sorted words across invocations of this method, but you reinitialize `sorted_words` to `[]` at the start of the method block.

I would suggest first trying to express your recursive solution in English as simply as possible and then seek to implement it.

For example, the following is an approach which seems to be in line with what you are trying to do:

```
def sorted_array(array)
  lowest_value prepended to the sorted_value of the array with the lowest_value removed
end
```

I'm sharing the above because it appears that you're new to Ruby and just implementing the above in an idiomatic fashion will be a good challenge.

Comment: Okay. that makes a lot of sense. It's going to take some time to digest what you said. I can probably figure it out from here but will take some time. Thank you.